# The local source doesn't exist Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference

Tags: c#, winforms, nuget, devexpress, nuget-package

I am trying to Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference
I do all steps but always i end up with this error:

> The local source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 19.1\Components\System\Components\Packages' doesn't exist

I can't find out why this problem is happend because now i am using DevExpress 19.2
Any suggestion,Thanks in advance. 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to do a solution wide search for the string "19.1" in Visual Studio ? (Ctrl + Shift + F)

Comment: I searched in the project file,Since you mentioned it now I tried search in entire solution and it is worked .Thank you very much

Comment: You're very welcome. It has happened to me in the past a couple of times too. Cheers.

Answer (score 15):

In Visual Studio, you may go to `Tools>Nuget Package Manager>Package Manager Settings` under `Package Sources` subgroup at left, and then **uncheck the missed references** for `Package Sources` ,as shown in picture below :

[image]

This may help you getting rid of this error.

Comment: Maybe late to comment, but this solution does work for me. Thanks.

Comment: To take effect it might be required to push "Clear All NuGet Cache(s)" button from General tab

Comment: Thanks you, this was killing me for hours